# Change Binding in main window after being called with $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs

I call a my controller with $routeProvider like this:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: "partials/main.html",
        controller: "AppCtrl"
    });
```

So the focus of `$scope` in the controller will change only the content of `partials/main.html`.
I would need to change `{{status}}` in index.html, but it won't change if I do `$scope.status = 'ready';` in the controller, it will change only if it was in main.html.
How can I make this work ?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope associated with AppCtrl should prototypically inherit from the scope associated with the controller you have defined in index.html.  Define a method on that controller, and then you can call it from your child controller/scope (because of the way [JavaScript prototypal inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs/14049482#14049482) works):

```
function MainCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.updateStatus = function(newStatus) {
       $scope.status = newStatus;
   }
}

function AppCtrl($scope) {
   ...
   $scope.updateStatus(....);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/eMaBR/).  In the fiddle, I don't use ng-view, but it still shows the concept.

Comment: Wow cool stuff ! Sorry if it sounded like a stupid question but I started not long ago. Thanks for your reply.